# How to consume Google Safe Browsing API v4 from Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm having trouble consuming the google safe browsing api v4. I'm sure this should be easy but its already taking me some time. I always get error **400 bad request**.  here is my code :

```
var
  idHttp : TIdHTTPEx;
  url : string;
  slTemp : TStringList;
  memoryStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  idHttp := TIdHTTPEx.Create(nil); // parent class is TIdHTTP, inherited to be able to execute HTTPS
  slTemp := TStringList.Create;
  memoryStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    idHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

    url := 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=' + GOOGLE_SAFE_BROWSING_API_KEY + ' HTTP/1.1';
    slTemp.Text := '{"client":{"clientId":"iGame","clientVersion":"1.0.0"},"threatInfo":{"threatTypes":"MALWARE","platformTypes":"WINDOWS","threatEntryTypes":"URL","threatEntries":[{"url":"http://www.hyxyg.com/default.php"},{"url":"https://jsonlint.com/"}]}}';

    idHttp.Post(url, slTemp, memoryStream);
    memo1.Text := memoryStream.ToString;

  finally
    memoryStream.Free;
    slTemp.Free;
    idHttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I tried checking [this](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/07/11/using-the-google-safe-browsing-api-from-delphi/) but it is using lower version. Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried using [this](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/indy-10-6-https-post/) as suggested by one of the comment, but still the same error **400 bad request**. the example was OK though.

```
var
  idHttp : TIdHTTPEx; // parent class is TIdHTTP, inherited to be able to execute HTTPS
  url : string;
  requestBody : TStream;
  sTemp : string;
begin
  url := 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=' + GOOGLE_SAFE_BROWSING_API_KEY + ' HTTP/1.1';
  //url := 'https://httpbin.org/post';

  idHttp := TIdHTTPEx.Create(nil);
  requestBody := nil;
  try

    idHttp.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    idHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

    sTemp := '{"client":{"clientId":"iGame","clientVersion":"1.0.0"},"threatInfo":{"threatTypes":"MALWARE","platformTypes":"WINDOWS","threatEntryTypes":"URL","threatEntries":[{"url":"http://www.hyxyg.com/default.php"},{"url":"https://jsonlint.com/"}]}}';
    //sTemp := '{"日本語":42}';

    requestBody := TStringStream.Create(sTemp, TEncoding.UTF8);
    sTemp := idHttp.Post(url, requestBody);

    memo1.Text := sTemp + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + idHttp.ResponseText;

  finally
    requestBody.Free;
    idHttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Some hints here: https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/indy-10-6-https-post/

Comment: I tried but still error.. I updated my question using the hint you suggested

Comment: The " HTTP/1.1" at the end of the URI must be an error, try without

Comment: thanks, tested and it is now working.. can you make your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The " HTTP/1.1" at the end of the URI must be an error, try without it.